# Lista en C++ de 10 millones de nodos

Tags: c++

estoy intentando hacer un ejercicio en el que tengo que crear una lista con 10 millones de numeros distintos y posteriormente ordenarla, pero solo me deja introducir en la lista hasta 9999 numeros, si añado más el programa se crashea.

Gracias por responder.

Comment: ¿Qué significa "*el programa se crashea*"? ¿Qué problemas estás teniendo? ¿Qué errores ves en pantalla? ¿Cómo están implementados los nodos y la lista? ¿Qué cabeceras estás usando? ¿Cómo insertas nodos? ¿Cuál es el algoritmo de ordenación? ¿Cómo introduces los datos?

Comment: Bienvenido @Wolframito74 a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Usa long double para los tipos de datos de los numeros.

Comment: con 32 bits (es decir, un `int`, puedes almacenar números de hasta 2.000 millones ... ¿Por qué crees que usar `long double` solucionará el problema?